# What is the story of Budha grabbing the Star Rohini?

Tags: ramayana

During the episode of Sita's abduction in the Valmiki Ramayana, it is [mentioned](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/aranya/sarga49/aranya_49_frame.htm) that Budha grabs the Rohini in firmament.

> इति उक्त्वा मैथिलीम् वाक्यम् प्रिय अर्हाम् प्रिय वादिनीम् || ३-४९-१५
>    अभिगम्य सुदुष्ट आत्मा राक्षसः काम मोहितः |
>    जग्राह रावणः सीताम् बुधः खे रोहिणीम् इव ||       ३-४९-१६
>
> On saying that sentence to Maithili, who by herself is a nice talker and who is a proper one for addressing with nice words, that verily evil-minded demon Ravana maddened by lust drew nigh of Seetha and grabbed her, as Budha, the mercury grabs the Star Rohini in firmament. [3-49-15b, 16]

My question is which scriptures describes the complete story of Budha grabbing his mother Rohini?

Comment: Subhash Kak writes about the scientific significance of the above in one of his papers.

Comment: The translator has made a small error. Budha is the Planet **Mercury**; **Brihaspati** or **Guru** is Jupiter.

Comment: Yes @surya I will edit my question.

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani If you also ask in your questions the significance of this event, I will answer it.

Comment: @amitsaxena but that will be the half of the answer. I also want to know the scriptural basis of this story

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani In that case, you could ask the significance separately in another question as an extension

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani I think you can use Sanskrit word **Budha** rather than some foreign name.

Comment: There might be story of it. But I think this might be related to astrology as it is said "in the firmament". Budha(mercury)  reaching the rohini star. Just a guess.